# React native card flip animation on tap

Tags: reactjs, animation, react-native, react-animated

I've got 2 cards, which can be flipped when tapped on.
Presently both the cards are flipping when any of the cards is tapped.
I want only the tapped card to flip.
How to get this done?
Sample code is available here https://snack.expo.io/rkBr-Ezpb

Comment: index the cards and on tap use that index

Comment: Is your problem resolved using above code snippet? If not, then you can go with other option react-native-flip-card.